# Custom Messages in Bluetooth Mesh

Tags: bluetooth, mesh-network

I am using Bluetooth Mesh technology for a project. The Bluetooth mesh works on flooding, and the message types are defined in the profile. However, I could not find whether I can include a custom payload in the messages to be delivered across the network. Is it possible to do this in Bluetooth Mesh? If yes, please suggest any resources that explain the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should visit the Bluetooth SIG. They own and publish all Bluetooth standards. They also maintain a comprehensive list of all specifications including those dealing with 'mesh':
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

And Nordic also provides extensive documentation with examples for its nRF5 SDK for Mesh:
https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fstruct_sdk%2Fstruct%2Fsdk_mesh_latest.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have read the specifications but I am still not sure about having a custom payload in the messages in Mesh. To my understanding, Bluetooth mesh provides fixed message types to get/set/modify the states of the connected devices. I am unsure whether we can pass a string between the devices via mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Mesh is based on Model interaction. If your application does not fit into available (defined by SIG) models, you can create your own (Vendor) models. In that case you can define opcodes (which should not interfere with opcodes of other messages) and customize transferred data.

More information on how to create you own model, in case you are using Nordic SDKs you can find here: [for nRF Connect SDK](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/ug_bt_mesh_vendor_model_dev_overview.html) or [for nRF Mesh SDK](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.meshsdk.v1.0.1%2Fmd_doc_getting_started_how_to_models.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had to move to another technology for some other reasons but I will definitely check out your references.